# How to remove file

Tags: php, file

We have a script, `/scripts/ourscript.php` and a file, `/media/movie1.flv`.

How can we remove this file, when we run `ourscript.php`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`unlink()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php)

```
$success = unlink("../media/movie1.flv");
echo "File was ". ($success ? "" : "not ") ."deleted";
```

Comment: in which case $success can be false?

Comment: @Happy: if the file was not successfully deleted (not found, incorrect permissions, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `unlink("/media/movie1.flv");`

[Here's](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) DOC on `unlink` function. Do keep in mind that the user running your *script* (usually Apache's user) needs WRITE permissions on the file you are your to delete.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the [`unlink()`](http://fr.php.net/unlink) function in your `ourscript.php` script.

For example :

```
$success = unlink('/media/movie1.flv');
if ($success === false) {
    // TODO : the file has not been deleted ; deal with that problem
}
```

Note, though, that `unkink()` will generate a warning if there's a failure... So, you might want to configure [`display_errors`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) properly, or use the [`@` operator](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

*(Even if using the `@` operator is generally not such a good idea)*

Comment: @Happy : when the deletion doesn't work -- for instance, when the file doesn't exist, or when you don't have the required permissions

Answer (score 0):

Use the `unlink` function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

```
<?php
unlink('/media/movie1.flv');
?>
```