# Change file contents

Tags: php, file

We have a script, `/scripts/ourscript.php` and a file, `/texts/elvis.txt`.

**How can we change contents of this file, when we run `ourscript.php`?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `file_put_contents()` method to set the contents of a file.

If you need just to **save new data**, you can do:

```
$elvis = 'Contents here';
$fileName = '..' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'texts' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'elvis.txt';
if (file_put_contents($fileName, $elvis) === false)
{
    // Handle error here.
}
```

If, instead of saving data, you need to **change existing data**, do:

```
$fileName = '..' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'texts' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'elvis.txt';
$elvis = file_get_contents($fileName);
// Do changes to $elvis here.
if (file_put_contents($fileName, $elvis) === false)
{
    // Handle error here.
}
```

Finally, if you need to **append something new to existing contents**, use:

```
$elvis = PHP_EOL . 'Contents to append to existing stuff here';
$fileName = '..' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'texts' . PATH_SEPARATOR . 'elvis.txt';

// Noticed FILE_APPEND as third argument?
if (file_put_contents($fileName, $elvis, FILE_APPEND) === false)
{
    // Handle error here.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

While MainMa has given you a direct answer, I'll point you to:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

Since it seems that you might have more of [these questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4203642/how-to-remove-file), which could have been easily answered by looking at the documentation.

Also by figuring things out with the help of the documentation you'll learn how to solve such problems on your own, you know independence is a nice thing to have :)